# popups stopped working after "concrete-izing" my bootstrap site

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, concrete5, concrete

This is the first time I use bootstrap in combination with concrete and I ran in to a little problem. The popups in which you edit and add new elements stopped working. Instead of loading in front of your page they now load as a separate page. On this separate page style and JavaScript isn't properly referred to which makes them useless. In other themes it still works so the installation of concrete it self isn't the problem here I guess.

So I see this:
[image: So I see this]

Instead of this:
[image: Instead of this]

Did any of you have the same problem? If so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a javascript error on the front-end that is interfering with C5's twitter-bootstrap js.  Check to see if you have more than one instance of jquery running, you may be including one in your theme that is conflicting with the default jquery in C5.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. here is a link to the site www.ramonbettings.com/concrete. (It is still in a very early stage.) I used the safari developer code inspector but it only gave one irrelevant error about an IE6 background fix.

Comment: nothing jumps out to me from the front end... would probably need access to the backend to really troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks for taking a look at it. I created an account for entering the back end. http://www.ramonbettings.com/concrete/index.php/login/ user:stackoverflow pswrd:stackoverflow

Comment: I see a javascript error when I enter edit mode.  Looking at your javascript, you are loading jquery more than once on the page.  Once in the header and once in the footer.  I would start by getting rid of that second instance of jquery (the footer one).

Comment: getting rid of the second instance did the trick. Thanks man really appreciate it!